# How to obtain a list of IP addresses of all available android device

Tags: android, udp

1. Obtain a List of IP addresses of all available android Devices.
2. Establish connection with one of IP.
3. Send Data to the Selected IP?.

If any body  done this already, a little help would be great.

Comment: Means you will create Hotspot on your android mobile, And you want to get list of connected devices with your hotspot?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to search for devices on your WiFi network. Then create a list with the devices (IP-addresses) you found. If you click on a device, send the data to the IP that belongs to that device.

To detect wether or not any device you find in the network is an Android device, is something else.

This article might be helpful to get you started, along with its subarticles: http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/index.html